# i18next interpolation in Russian language

Tags: string-interpolation, i18next

I'm trying to use i18next with interpolation in my React app

Here is examples in React code

```
 {i18n.t('hours', {ns:'namespace', count: 100})}
        <Trans i18nKey='hours' ns='namespace' count={10}/>
        {t('hours', {count: 1})}
```

Here is my 'namespace.json'

```
  "hours_one": "час",
  "hours_few": "часа",
  "hours_many": "часов"
  "hours": "часы {{count}}"
```

here is my output

```
часы 100
часы {{count}}
часы 1
```

As you can see in does not work. I don't know why.
Can someone help me to understand what i'm doing wrong?

Config

```
const resources = {
  ru: {
    namespace: namespaceRU
  }
};
i18n
  .use(Backend)
  .use(LanguageDetector)
  .use(initReactI18next)

  .init({
    resources,
    fallbackLng: 'ru',
    debug: true,
    supportedLngs: ['ru'],
    interpolation: {
      escapeValue: false, // not needed for react as it escapes by default
    },
    react: {
      useSuspense: false
    },
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to change 2 things in your `Trans` component:

1. pass `t` to `Trans`
2. use the `values` prop in order to pass the `count`

```js
<Trans t={t} i18nKey='hours' ns='namespace' values={{count: 10}}/>
```